# ngrx select strings are types?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'd like to say that I'm at beginner's level in both Typescript and Angular (including ngrx).

I'm trying to wrap my head around how the **select** method of the **Store** class can accept a string literal as a parameter. Here's code:

```
export interface AppState {
    readonly tutorial: Tutorial[];
}

export class ReadComponent {

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.tutorials = store.select('tutorial');
  }
}
```

Now, I see the the **AppState** class has a tutorial property, and that seems to be what the call store.select('tutorial') is going for, but how though? How is it that if I change the literal being passed to select ex. store.select('yadayada'), the compiler issues an error *Argument of type '"yadayada"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"tutorial"'*. How are "tutorial" and "yadayada" types? Why is the compiler taking a string literal as a type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It infers it as a key on the store object type and can infer the value type from that. For a example you can define a generic function:

`const getKey = <T>(obj: T, key: keyof T) => obj[key] ;`

It will correctly infer the return type and give a compiler error if key is not a key of T. You can explicitly type the return value of the function as T[keyof T].
Typescript generics and type inference is insanely powerful.